# How to allocate disk space from one filesystem to another?

Tags: installation, partitioning, disk-usage

I have Ubuntu 12.04 on dedicated server with 2 TB hard disk, while running a daemon I got error running low on disk space, when I check memory status by running df -h it shows that my rootfs have 20 GB disk space and I almost ran out of it however I have rest free disk space in /dev/md3

Is there any command I can allocate more disk space to /dev/root ?

This is the output of df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs           20G   18G  170M 100% /
/dev/root        20G   18G  170M 100% /
devtmpfs         16G  4.0K   16G   1% /dev
none            3.2G  260K  3.2G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             16G     0   16G   0% /run/shm
/dev/md3        1.8T  118M  1.7T   1% /home
```

Comment: Add the output of `df -h` to your question.

Comment: What do you do that takes up 18G? If it is MYSQL you can change that so it stores the databases in /home. That can get you several GB's.

Comment: Installed crypto currencies like bitcoin litecoin etc

Comment: Are you sure you are using Ubuntu, because I've never seen it give that /dev/root nonsense.  What is your root *really* on?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gparted](http://gparted.org/) to edit (resize) your partitions.

Make a bootable CD or USB to perform the work.

I find it very reliable and easy to use.  However, I'll advise you to be careful if you don't have your important databased up. While the commands and options are very clear, if you make a mistake you could wipe out a partition.

As far as I know, that is the only (reliable) method that I'm familiar with.

Comment: I think I have mentioned that I am using the OS on a dedicated server don't have access to it

Answer (score 0):

Since /home is in a raid array, and it doesn't look like you are using lvm, you are out of luck.  You will have to try moving some of your large data files to /home.  You can replace the originals with a symbolic link to the new location.

Comment: I have done that only moved files from root to /home